# Excel Pivot Table Question - Filtering / Trying to Find Best Visualization Practices

Tags: excel, pivot-table, jira

I am struggling in an Excel Pivot Table situation, and getting nowhere. Quick explanation as to what I am trying to achieve -

I exported data from a Jira project, and I am trying to point out Custom Fields that never get used. In the Pivot Table I have added each Custom Field in the Values section, and calculate each field by 'Count.' This give me the data I want to see - the number of times a Custom Field is being used in the project.

The idea is that I want to show all of the Custom Fields that Count equals 0. With my current Pivot Table structure I am not able to filter, sort, etc. anything on my Values column. All I can see is all of the data under Values (seen in screenshot).

Does anyone know of ways I can demonstrate only the Custom Fields that equal 0 here? I feel like I am stuck. Any advice would be so much appreciated.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rb25.png)

Comment: What does the source data look like?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi - The data source is an export of all Issues (about 400) and all fields from 1 Jira project. With all of that data I created a Pivot Table. The Values portion of the Pivot Table is populated with the Count of all custom fields from the project. Does that help?